# Kubernetes rollout deployment history CHANGE-CAUSE field is always <none>

Tags: kubernetes

I just ran

`kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx:1.18.0 --replicas=2 --port=80`

to create a deployment.

Then edited the image of that deployment

`kubectl set image deploy nginx nginx=nginx:1.19.8`

Then looked at its rollout history

`kubectl rollout history deployment nginx`

However, the change-cause column is always `<none>`.
From the [wiki](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-a-deployment), I have understood that this should at least contain the command that was used to trigger the change.

I seem to be having the same issue as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/54014).
Except since then, `--record` has been deprecated. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73814500/record-has-been-deprecated-then-what-is-the-alternative) question, there seem to be no alternatives.

What's going on with the change-cause field and why isn't it being filled the way the wiki says it will?

I am fully aware of the possibility of adding my own annotations, but I explicitly just want to know why the commands aren't being put into the change-cause field, as is claimed by the wiki.

Comment: Not k8s expert but from what I have researched the `set image` command doesn't automatically update that field. So it's designed that way

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Yeah, I guess. The problem is that these commands and their description are found on the wiki, which means it's simply written wrong.